# Exit code 0, no errors, and no output

Tags: python

I am running this python sentiment analysis and when I run it there is no errors and no output. I'm new this this but I can't seem to find any reason through my research.

I've run it through pycharms debugger and got an exit code of 0. When I run it through but the pycharms IDE or my command line, it just runs and then nothing happens.

class TwitterClient(object):

```
def __init__(self):

    consumer_key = "ConsumerKey" 
    consumer_secret = "ConsumerSecret" 
    access_token = "AccessToken" 
    access_token_secret = "AccessTokenSecret" 
    try:
        self.auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
        self.auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
        self.api = tweepy.API(self.auth)
    except:
        print("Error: Authentication Failed")
def clean_tweet(self, tweet):

    return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t]) | (\w+:\ / \ / \S+)", " ", tweet).split())
def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):

    analysis = TextBlob(self.clean_tweet(tweet))
    if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        return 'positive'
    elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        return 'neutral'
    else:
        return 'negative'
def get_tweets(self, query, count=10):

    tweets = []
    try:
        fetched_tweets = self.api.search(q="Microsoft", count=5)
        for tweet in fetched_tweets:
            parsed_tweet = {}
            parsed_tweet['text'] = tweet.text
            parsed_tweet['sentiment'] = self.get_tweet_sentiment(tweet.text)
            if tweet.retweet_count > 0:
                if parsed_tweet not in tweets:
                    tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
            else:
                tweets.append(parsed_tweet)
        return tweets
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print("Error : " + str(e))
def main():
    api = TwitterClient()
    tweets = api.get_tweets(query='Microsoft', count=50)
    ptweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'positive']
    print("Positive tweets percentage: {} %".format(100 * len(ptweets) / len(tweets)))
    ntweets = [tweet for tweet in tweets if tweet['sentiment'] == 'negative']
    print("Negative tweets percentage: {} %".format(100 * len(ntweets) / len(tweets)))
    print("Neutral tweets percentage: {} % \
      ".format(100 * len(tweets - ntweets - ptweets) / len(tweets)))
    print("\n\nPositive tweets:")
    for tweet in ptweets[:10]:
        print(tweet['text'])
    print("\n\nNegative tweets:")
    for tweet in ntweets[:10]:
        print(tweet['text'])
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python...

Comment: more typically, pay serious attention to the last two lines. And let me clarify for your question: Yes, your (desired) code is not being executed at all. AND, you should take a look on [stackoverflow markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) too.

Comment: Your last two lines are inside the main() function. The main() function is never called from anywhere. Put the last two lines outside your main function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

must be in the "global scope". The indentation is incorrect causing the if-statement to be in the main function.